# ArcGIS Web AppBuilder browser privacy error

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am trying to launch `ArcGIS Web App Builder` for the very first time in `Windows 10`.

1. Download and unzip the latest 2.2.1 package.
2. Run  `startup.bat`.
3. Get the Device name under `This PC > Properties > Device name`.
4. Paste `https://[yourmachinename]:3344/webappbuilder/` in the browser (Chrome) and press `enter`. This returns an error:

`Privacy error Your connection is not private`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `localhost` instead of `yourmachinename` and tell chrome to ignore localhost certificate issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562585

Comment: It works thank you, you can put this in your answer, and I will accept it. However, Chrome still says that the connection is not secure, should I be concerned about this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `localhost` instead of `yourmachinename` and tell chrome to ignore localhost certificate issues.

From [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35562585):

> In Chrome, put in chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost in the
> address bar.
>
> Enable the option that says "Allow invalid certificates for resources
> loaded from localhost".
>
> Restart Chrome, and it should allow the site.

As to whether you should be concerned, from [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/241392):

> **It's most likely fine.**
> There are a few situations in which you want to
> communicate with localhost using HTTPS - such as running a local
> webserver for web development purposes or some other service that
> offers a web interface.
>
> The way to do it "properly" is to generate a self-signed certificate,
> set up your web server to use that certificate, and then manually
> import that certificate as a trusted certificate. This is a tedious
> process, and in order to remove this friction, browsers give you the
> option of pretending like https://localhost is sending some trusted
> certificate, even though it's not.
>
> So is this secure? That depends on your threat model. For day-to-day
> browsing activities, you'll likely be fine. It's difficult for an
> attacker even in your local network to impersonate localhost, since
> it's written directly in your hosts file, which on most setups has
> higher priority than DNS - which means even with a compromised DNS
> server, connections to localhost still would not be redirected to the
> attacker.
>
> So why is this not the default if it's most likely secure? Because
> it's not the "expected" behavior of a browser. The expected behavior
> is that upon connecting to a host using HTTPS, the certificate is
> validated and the connection is refused if the certificate is invalid.
> You as end-user have to make a conscious decision to change this
> behavior and allow this exception.
>
> So when would this be insecure? When would it actually pose a threat?
> To be honest, I struggle to think of an example that isn't completely
> contrived. Strange hostname resolution configurations in which
> localhost would be resolved via DNS and spoofed to be some host other
> than 127.0.0.1 would come to mind, but that is a very unlikely
> scenario, and one in which the user has to go out of their way to
> configure their system to be vulnerable. However, I don't want to say
> "it is perfectly fine in every possible setup", since there is always
> a chance I am missing something.